# Python ctypes UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, windows, encoding, ctypes

I'm checking for an active window title every second, as follows:

```
import ctypes, time

GetForegroundWindow = ctypes.windll.user32.GetForegroundWindow
GetWindowTextLength = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowTextLengthW
GetWindowText = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowTextW

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    act_id = GetForegroundWindow()
    length = GetWindowTextLength(act_id)
    buff = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(length + 1)
    GetWindowText(act_id, buff, length + 1)
    print(buff.value)
```

It works, but printing the title of some windows causes the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u017d' in position
0: character maps to <undefined>
```

How should I solve this encoding error?

Comment: Try this https://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails

Comment: You already have a UTF-16 buffer. If `sys.stdout.isatty()`, just call `kernel32.WriteConsoleW`.

Comment: On an unrelated note, you're getting and passing `act_id` as a C `int` value (`c_int` is the default return type and integer argument conversion). According to [32-bit and 64-bit Interoperability](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872017), user32 handles are only 32-bit, so what you're doing is technically safe. However, you have to know whether a given handle type really is not a (possibly 64-bit) pointer.

Comment: That's a weird error -- [U+017D](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/17d/index.htm) certainly isn't undefined.

Comment: As a matter of terminological correcness, U+017D is unambiguously a Unicode code point.  It cannot be defined in any other encoding.  But I guess you are fundamentally correct that the issue may be that the string is being mapped to a different encoding which does not support this character.

Comment: @tripleee, oh, you're just nitpicking the error message, not the error itself. IMO, it's unambiguously clear in context that the codec doesn't define a *mapping* from U+017D to an encoded value. If kreon had included the complete traceback we'd know which codec it is (e.g. cp850.py), not that it really matters.

Comment: Agree that a complete trace would be important for properly troubleshooting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import ctypes, time
GetForegroundWindow = ctypes.windll.user32.GetForegroundWindow
GetWindowTextLength = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowTextLengthW
GetWindowText = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowTextW
WriteConsoleW = ctypes.windll.kernel32.WriteConsoleW
STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = - 11
outhandle = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    act_id = GetForegroundWindow()
    length = GetWindowTextLength(act_id)
    buff = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(length + 1)
    GetWindowText(act_id, buff, length + 1)
    chars_written = ctypes.c_int(0)
    title = buff.value + "\n"
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.WriteConsoleW(outhandle, title, len(title), ctypes.byref(chars_written), None)
```

This works well.
Now for example 'č' is printed as 'c' and that is sufficient for me.

Comment: `buff` is null-terminated, which you don't need. So just set `buff[-1] = u'\n'` and pass `buff` directly to `WriteConsoleW`.